Add comma to animated counter
I've tried everything I can find online about this but they all seem to deal with static numbers, not animated numbers.
Is it possible to have commas added to my values as the number increases using this by modifying this function?
  animateCounter(element) {
    let counter = 0;
    let increment = 1;

    const matches = /(\+)?(\d+)(\w)?/.exec(element.dataset.count);
    const before = matches[1] ?? '';
    const after = matches[3] ?? '';

    if (matches[2] > 1000) {
      increment = 50;
    } else if (matches[2] > 100) {
      increment = 10;
    }

    const step = timestamp => {
      counter += increment;

      element.innerText = `${before}${counter}${after}`;

      if (counter < +matches[2]) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame( step );
      }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame( step );
  }


Just add the commas to counter before you assign it to innerText. At that point it's just static text.
